# Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f^n(x)$ convergent on some interval $[0,\varepsilon)$ assuming that function is continuous non-decreasing such that f(0)

Tags: analysis, functions

I have started wondering is this true working on one problem. If we have a function $f:[0,\infty)\mapsto [0,\infty)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ otherwise, can we claim that the  series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f^n(x)$$ converges on some interval $[0,\varepsilon)$ assuming that function is continuous and nondecreasing?

To clarify: $f^{n+1}(x)=f\circ f^n(x)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I believe it is equivalent with existance of such $x$ that the series converges since in that case we can use that it is bounded by that $x$ in some interval $(0,\delta)$.

Comment: If $f^n$ denotes the composition then $f(x) = \sqrt x $ is a counterexample, or $f(x) = 2x$, or any function satisfying $f(x) \ge x$ for small $x$.

Comment: Exactly, thank you very much-I’ve got stuck somehow.